# My MacBook Air M1 (2020) drains the battery faster than expected when I keep my Android phone connected to it

Tags: battery, macbook, battery-life, thunderbolt, macbook-air

The battery drains very quickly on my MacBook Air M1 (2020) when I keep an Android phone connected to it. I use it for app development.

Is there any way I could stop the Android device from charging? If not, would it affect my battery’s lifespan if I plug my MacBook to power always while the Android phone is connected?

Comment: “If not, would it affect my battery’s lifespan if I plug my MacBook to power always while the Android phone is connected?” You should not be concerned about battery lifespan like this on modern MacBooks from the last 10 years or so. Hyper awareness of battery conditioning is not really an issue anymore for MacBooks and many other PC and Chromebook machines. The power management is much better and it will not cause your battery to die earlier to do something like this. Just keep it plugged in. No worries.